# C# Expression trees - allowing byte to be assignable to int type

Tags: c#

I am using the code below in the context of a data access code in which I create business objects from a data table item (System.Data.DataRow) dynamically. I would like to be able assign a byte column retrieved from the datarow to an integer field on my business object.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestConsole {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var targetExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "target");
            var valueExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(targetExp, typeof(SomeClass)), "SomeInt");
            var assignmentExpression = Expression.Assign(propertyExpression, Expression.Convert(valueExp, typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty("SomeInt").PropertyType));
            var compliedExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(assignmentExpression, targetExp, valueExp).Compile();
            var obj = new SomeClass();
            byte ten = 10;
            compliedExpression.Invoke(obj, 10);
            compliedExpression.Invoke(obj, (int)10); //this works and i want to do this cast using expression trees, any idea?
            compliedExpression.Invoke(obj, ten); //Specified cast is not valid.
            Console.WriteLine(obj.SomeInt);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class SomeClass {
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think dtb is on the right lines...but I think you want to change the types of your parameters to the correct types...and change the lambda type to be of Action of My Class, int

Comment: Personally I, when I try to create new expressions dynamically I get Linq pad to visualize the expression tree I want to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a boxed `byte` and are trying to unbox it to an `int`. That is not valid.

```
object obj = (byte)10;
int i = (int)obj; // InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
```

What you can do instead is call the [Convert.ToInt32 Method (Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
// i == 10
```

or the [Convert.ChangeType Method (Object, Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx):

```
int i = (int)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(int));
// i == 10
```

Comment: OP asked for this in Expressions.

Comment: @Aron: OP seems to be familiar with Expressions, so I focused on the problem and potential solutions. It should be fairly trivial to convert this to Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Expression.Convert` I believe it will work as cast